# Material UI, rendering Row component with an extra prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/), and looking at the source code, it accepts a `components` property. I know that [TableRow](https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/) accepts a `hover` prop, which, if set to true, will [highlight the current row](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#EnhancedTable.js) as feedback for the user.

My component renders the data before I make any changes:

```
<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  title="Purchases"
  columns={tableColumnsPurchases}
  data={purchases}
/>
```

But the moment I add the custom `Row` component:

```
<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  title="Purchases"
  columns={tableColumnsPurchases}
  data={purchases}
  components={{
    Row: props => <TableRow hover />
  }}
/>
```

It stops rendering all rows. I tried doing,

```
  Row: props => <TableRow hover {...props} />
```

But that throws errors of unrecognized props.

What am I doing wrong here?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cxrof?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Getting rid of the `components` prop makes it work, but I need it to work with the `components` prop because I want to add `hover`, as you can see.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you provide a stackblitz example or add more code

Comment: Sure, I've updated the OP

Comment: If you want the hover highlight to show you probably want to do something with the row right? Because when you pass a function to `onRowClick` to your table it will automatically enable the hover, so you won't need to override the Row component.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but how could I get this way to work? I might need to override the Row component in the future, and it's not working for me right now.

Comment: Also, `onRowClick={props => console.log("props", props)}` logs absolutely nothing related to the rowData.

Comment: `components={<TableRow hover {...props} />}` have you tried this?

Comment: Props is undefined, did you mean `components={{Row: props => <TableRow hover {...props} />}}`? If so, then yes, I've tried that.

Comment: on the `<TableRow/>` component the props should be coming from parent, is it?

Comment: In `onRowClick` the second argument is the rowData, first one is the event. Also, I think that if you're going to override the row component you should not pass all the props to @material-ui/core TableRow, but rather create your own version that handles all the logic.

Comment: Yes, please take a look at the CodeSandbox link in my question

Comment: @JapMul, running with `onRowClick` for now, but I'd love to get this way to work. In the future, I'll maybe just create my own `TableRow` component, I guess, thanks for the suggestion.